# Built in way to concatenate two Enumerators

Tags: ruby

Say you have:

```
enum1 = 1.upto(5)
enum2 = 7.upto(10)
```

I want:

```
enum_combined = enum1.some_method(enum2)
```

such that:

```
enum_combined.to_a #=> [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

I don't see any method on the Enumerator class that would do this, but before rolling my own solution I'd like make sure I'm not missing some built-in way to do this.

To be clear: I want the returned result to be another `Enumerator` object, since I want the entire calculation to be lazy.

### UPDATE

Per the linked duplicate, the way to achieve this is:

```
combined = [enum1, enum2].lazy.flat_map(&:lazy)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a new enumerator, iterating through your existing enumerators. Something like:

```
enum = Enumerator.new { |y|
  enum1.each { |e| y << e }
  enum2.each { |e| y << e }
}
```

Comment: @Jonah Within `enum` you can combine the enumerators into an array and iterate through them as per Spiro's answer or like Cary's deleted answer. Or something like `[enum1,enum2].each { |e| e.each { |i| y << i } }` will work.

Answer (score 1):

You can make `Enumerator` class extension like this:

```
class Enumerator
  def self.concat(*enumerators)
    self.new do |y|
      enumerators.each do |e|
        e.each {|x| y << x }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

and use it like that:

```
enum3 = Enumerator.concat(enum1, enum2)
```

Comment: Monkey-patching is a bad idea generally, but this is an elegant, clean way to achieve this.